# Mountable Engines - uninitialized constant Customer (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-engines

I created a Mountable Engine after this I created a file class in lib.

Like this:

path:   `/lib/dog.rb`

class:

```
    class Dog
      def initialize(breed, name)
      @breed = breed
      @name = name
    end

    def bark
      puts 'Ruff! Ruff!'
    end

    def display
      puts "I am of #{@breed} breed and my name is #{@name}"
    end
    end
```

I have a initializer in 
    `/config/initializers/scheduler.rb` with the content:

```
d = Dog.new('Labrador', 'Benzy')
```

When I initiate my rails app I receive this error:

```
uninitialized constant Dog (NameError)
```

I tried create a application.rb file in /config/ with the content `require '/lib/customer.rb'` or `require 'rails/all'` but doesn't work.

Comment: Pretty sure you'll need to use `EngineName::Dog.new("Labrador", "Benzy")`

Comment: Doest work same error @j-dexx

Comment: Sounds like the environment isn't setup by the time the initializer runs so rails hasn't loaded in all the files yet.

Comment: @engineersmnky I can't use application.rb. The file doesnt load

Comment: Sorry I forgot this was an engine. Your issue is that you are just requiring the file wrong. Try adding `require 'dog'` because `lib` will be considered the root for this.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue , modules where not loading. Solved the issue by specifying autoload_path in engine.rb

In engine **lib/engien_name/engine.rb**

```
class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/modules)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the guide here ? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

It says to include your class as:

```
module Dog
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
  end
end
```

but I don't believe this is only your case. You need to run through several steps, it isn't implemented as an ordinary Ruby library which is simply included.

Comment: my default engine.rb is: `module Alarm
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Alarm
  end
end` how can I add ?

Comment: I skimmed the guide you linked, but I think you're mistaken.  The code you are quoting is part of the Rails-specific `engine.rb` -- not the files the OP or myself are creating.  The problem the OP is referencing has to do with the fact that lib inside of engines aren't autoloaded by default (unlike in the main Rails app).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue.  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43681766/3352624) answer helpful.

Basically, the issue you are experiencing is caused by the fact that lib isn't autoloaded in engines in the way that lib is for the main Rails app.

From the referenced link, I found 2 solutions for this.

**Option 1: Autoloading**

You can enable autoloading for your engine's lib folder by editing your engine's `engine.rb` file in the engine's lib.  See https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html (section on Configuration).

Basically add `config.autoload_paths << File.expand_path("lib/some/path", __dir__)` to your engine.rb file.  In my case, since my files were in the same folder as my engine.rb file, I used `config.autoload_paths << File.expand_path('.', __dir__)`

**Option 2: Require**

If you want to avoid altering autoloading, you can require the file where it is needed.  Just add `require 'my_engine/class_or_module_needed'` to the top of the file it is needed in.