# rails: autoload files inside engine's lib directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autoload, rails-engines

I am working on this rails application with an engine which is sort of sub application adding some more routes to my existing application.

The concept is so powerful, thanks to rails.

But I am facing this weird challenge to autoload file changes inside my engines lib directory in development mode. Every time I make a change inside app directory of engine be it model or controller , it works flawlessly, but no changes to any files under lib directory get's picked up. Is there a way I can do this ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Rails::Engine docs](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html) you can autoload paths like-

```
class MyEngine < Rails::Engine
  # Add a load path for this specific Engine
  config.autoload_paths << File.expand_path("../lib/some/path", __FILE__)

  initializer "my_engine.add_middleware" do |app|
    app.middleware.use MyEngine::Middleware
  end
end
```

If you don't want to autoload, you can directly require the file in your class with the require statement-

```
require 'my_engine/my_object'
class MyModel < AR::Base
  ...
end
```

This will work because your Engine is already loaded in your app, so you can access libs inside of it.

Comment: The suggested File.expand_path("../lib/some/path", __FILE__) yields

Comment: From what I can tell, the 3 lines of code regarding middleware are not applicable to the OP's question (they are just part of the larger discussion of configuration in the docs).  All I needed (Rails 5) was adjusting autoload_paths.  Also worth noting, is that since my lib files were in the same folder as the `engine.rb`, my path was just `.` for `../lib/some/path`.

Answer (score -5):

Put the following code in your `config/application.rb`

```
config.eager_load_paths += ["#{Rails.root}/lib"]
```

If you want this only in development mode use the following

```
config.eager_load_paths += ["#{Rails.root}/lib"] if Rails.env.development?
```

Comment: The question is about `rails engine` not abut the complete `rails app`.